# Spritekit - How to create a hole like billiard's pockets?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am creating a game where a ball is moving on the screen and I would like to create a hole where the ball can go inside (as it happens in billiard)

Can that be a simple circle SKNode with a black background? In this case I should hide the ball when it will go over the hole (which is a really bad effect)

Any other features available / ideas?
Thank you

Comment: How about using a sknode with an image of a pocket and when the ball touches it you change the scale so it looks like it disappears down the whole

Comment: @Shaun07776 nice idea actually reducing the scale..! I gonna have a look of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do in this circumstance is create a SKSpriteNode for the hole, with just a black image as the circle. Then when the two nodes collide, you delete the ball node. I'm assuming you are doing this in your GameScene by the way

First, create an enum for your collision detector:

```
 enum ColliderType:UInt32 {
    case ball = 1
    case blackhole = 2
}
```

Creating a Basic Black Hole Node

```
let blackHole:SKNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "NameOfImage")
    blackHole.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: side.size.width/2)
    blackHole.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    //These 3 lines of code basically say to pay attention to collisions
    blackHole.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.blackhole.rawValue
    blackHole.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.ball.rawValue
    blackHole.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.ball.rawValue
    self.addChild(side)
```

Also, where you set the physics properties of your balls, insert this code

```
(Name of Sprite).physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.ball.rawValue
(Name of Sprite).physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.blackhole.rawValue
(Name of Sprite).physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.blackhole.rawValue
```

Then, this is where you detect collisions.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{
    //variable stores the two things contacting
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch(contactMask){

    case ColliderType.ball.rawValue | ColliderType.blackhole.rawValue:
        //deletes the ball as a Node
        contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()


    default:
        return



    }
}
```

Let me know if any of it is confusing or if I need to explain more

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Brennan! I will reduce the size of the ball and then remove it from parent after the collision..! great ;-)

Comment: Hello Developers, need your help and support. I am new in SpriteKit, right now I am learning SpriteKit from 0, I need demo app for billiards (pool table) game. I need for learning purpose. acutely I am confused where am i going to start ? It would be nice if you give me billiards demo app source code in swift. Thank you.